# Open Source ruby and rails projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-source

Which open source ruby or ruby on rails projects do you contribute to regularly?

Answer (score 7):

[Sinatra](http://sinatra.lighthouseapp.com/projects/9779-sinatra/tickets?q=all) and [Rack](http://rack.lighthouseapp.com/projects/22435-rack/tickets?q=all) are two of my favorite projects, since they're both relatively young, meaning they have much good work to be done.

If you're looking to contribute to projects, also see [my GitHub profile](http://github.com/nakajima), since I'm always looking for patches. :)

Answer (score 4):

I work on [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) and it's plugins a lot.  I'm going to be getting into [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) soon, it's a really good framework for creating a simple web app.

Answer (score 1):

I have contributed to [RSpec](http://rspec.info).

Answer (score 1):

I work on [rboard](http://github.com/radar/rboard), a forum system built for the latest versions of Rails and actively maintained. I also occasionally commit to the documentation for Rails itself too.

I'm also looking for patches on rboard, there's a large TODO.html file in there.

Answer (score 1):

Found this - [23 open source Ruby on Rails applications](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/23-amazing-and-open-source-ruby-on-rails-applications/)